# if statement when column in DB is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

guys i am making a grid library that uses hibernate and spring mvc to read data from db .. i have 2 table employee which has EPMID, EMPNAME, EMPAGE, SALARY, ADDRESS, department_id (refrences to department_id in department table ) and department which has department_id and name ... here is the Department.java

```
public class Department {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

@Column(name = "department_id")
private int depId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String depName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="department",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },   orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Employee> employees;}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "EMPID")
private int empId;

@Column(name = "EMPNAME")
private String empName;

@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
private String empAddress;

@Column(name = "SALARY")
private String salary;

@Column(name = "EMPAGE")
private int empAge;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
private Department department;}
```

and the function that adds teh employee in service

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = false)
public void addEmployee(String[] list, Employee employee) {
    employee.setEmpName(list[2]);
    employee.setEmpAge(Integer.parseInt(list[4]));
    employee.setEmpAddress(list[6]);
    employee.setSalary(list[1]);
    //employee.getDepartment().setDepId(Integer.parseInt(list[3]));
    Department dept = departmentDao.getDepartment(Integer.parseInt(list[3]));

    if(dept.equals(null)){
        employee.setDepartment(departmentDao.getDepartment(16));
    }
    employee.setDepartment(dept);

    this.employeeDao.addOrEditEmployee(employee);
}
```

but when entering department_id not found in the parent department_id .. a nullpointer exception occurs .. i want to set the department_id equals to 16 instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every class in Java has `java.lang.Object` as its superclass by default. Since the `equals` method is provided by Object class you are able to call it on `dept` object.

```
if (dept.equals(null)) {
    employee.setDepartment(departmentDao.getDepartment(16));
}
```

And null is not an object in Java. So the if statement should be:

```
if(dept == null) {
   \* ---- your code goes here --- *\
}
```